# How to use mean value theorem to prove this question?

Tags: calculus

Let $f:(a,b)\to \mathbb R$ be twice diff.
If $f''>0$ on $(a,b)$, then the graph of the function on $y=f(x)$ lies above any of its tangent lines

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Are we to prove it or what is the question?

Comment: You might search for something about "convex functions".

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Suppose $b>c>a$. To show $f(a) +f'(a)(c-a) \leq f(c)$ (what does that mean?), use MVT (how?), and the fact that $f'(x)$ is increasing within $(a,b)$ (why is that?).

Comment: I do not understand  f(a)+f′(a)(c−a)≤f(c) mean ?

Comment: So, I asked you what that means : )

Comment: sorry,I can not figure out it ...